# Indexing pdf/word using inguest-attachment plugin in elasticsearch via java code

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am trying to index my word/pdf document so that I created one util program using java to encode my files into base64 and then am trying to index them in ElasticSearch.

Please find my below code that I able to encode my files into base64. Now, I am not sure how can I index them in ElasticSearch

Please find my java code below.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "D:\\\\1SearchEngine\\testing.pdf";
    String encodedfile = null;
    RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;
    File file = new File(filePath);
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
        encodedfile = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
        //System.out.println(encodedfile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (restHighLevelClient != null) {
            restHighLevelClient.close();
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error closing ElasticSearch client: ");
    }

    try {
        restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest( "attach_local", "doc", "103");   
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
    jsonMap.put("resume", "Karthikeyan");
    jsonMap.put("postDate", new Date());
    jsonMap.put("resume", encodedfile);
    try {
        IndexResponse response = restHighLevelClient.index(request);
    } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
        if (e.status() == RestStatus.CONFLICT) {

        }
    }
}
```

Am using ElasticSearch 6.2.3 version and i have installed ingest-attachment plugin version 6.3.0

Am using below dependency for ElasticSearch Client

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please find my mapping details

```
PUT attach_local
{
  "mappings" : {
    "doc" : {
      "properties" : {
        "attachment" : {
          "properties" : {
            "content" : {
              "type" : "binary"
            },
            "content_length" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "content_type" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "language" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "resume" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT _ingest/pipeline/attach_local
{
  "description" : "Extract attachment information",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "resume"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now am getting the below error from java while create index

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: source is missing;2: content type is missing;
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ValidateActions.addValidationError(ValidateActions.java:26)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest.validate(IndexRequest.java:153)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:436)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:429)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:312)
    at com.es.utility.DocumentIndex.main(DocumentIndex.java:82)
```

Comment: For one the versions of ES and plugin have to match. Then you'll have to setup a named pipeline in the index specification call then use it in the indexing call. Post your code where you specify the mapping and your indexing code and we can help you

Comment: I have update my `mapping` details.,

Comment: I meant your index mapping. Anyway you have to set the pipeline up first, PUT _ingest/pipeline/attachment call before you can index docs. Also Change PUT my_index/my_type/my_id to PUT employee/details/1?pipeline=attachment

Comment: If you are new, a good way to learn is to look at ES github repo and their unit tests, see here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/99f88f15c5febbca2d13b5b5fda27b844153bf1a/server/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/ingest

Comment: @sramalingam24 - Thanks for sharing github repo.. I  have attached my index mappings details.

Comment: `resume` must be in `binary` type. Also there is no need to add `keyword` field for every text field.

Comment: @vakarami - Am trying to indexing via java api., do you have any idea about it.?

Comment: mapping is separate from java api. Just change your mapping and update it by curl. Then post your documents to elastic like this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html#java-docs-index-doc

Comment: @vakarami - i made the changes as per your suggestions., i have updated my code and mappings details also. now am getting `Validation Failed: 1: source is missing;2: content type is missing;` error from java while create index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution, how to index PDF/WORD document in ElasticSearch via Java APIs

```
String filePath = "D:\\\\1SearchEngine\\testing.pdf";
String encodedfile = null;
RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;
File file = new File(filePath);
try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
    encodedfile = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    if (restHighLevelClient != null) {
        restHighLevelClient.close();
    }
} catch (final Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error closing ElasticSearch client: ");
}

try {
    restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}


Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
jsonMap.put("Name", "Karthikeyan");
jsonMap.put("postDate", new Date());
jsonMap.put("resume", encodedfile);

IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("attach_local", "doc", "104")
        .source(jsonMap)
        .setPipeline("attach_local");

try {
    IndexResponse response = restHighLevelClient.index(request);
} catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
    if (e.status() == RestStatus.CONFLICT) {

    }
}
```

Mapping Details :

```
PUT attach_local
{
  "mappings" : {
    "doc" : {
      "properties" : {
        "attachment" : {
          "properties" : {
            "content" : {
              "type" : "binary"
            },
            "content_length" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "content_type" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "language" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "resume" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


PUT _ingest/pipeline/attach_local
{
  "description" : "Extract attachment information",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "resume"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Good deal amigo

Comment: Thanks., still challenge is there to search with the content of pdf